# Intersection of two maximum heaps

Tags: algorithm, heap, set-intersection

I have two maximum-heaps (represented in arrays), H1 of size m and H2 of size n, with n>m.
I have to create a third max-heap with elements coming from the intersection of H1 and H2.

The elementary solution (scan the two arrays) takes O(n*m) time, and doesn't take advantage of the max-heap properties.

Other ideas?

Comment: `O(nlogn + mlogm)` can be easily achieved, obviously. Wondering if there is a linear solution similar to merging two sorted arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two heaps, you can compute the intersection of elements in O(M log M + N log N) time, and the result is ordered. An ordered array is already a heap, so no further time is required.

Python-syntax example:

```
# Given arrays heap1, heap2.

intersection = []
while len(heap1) > 0 and len(heap2) > 0:
    if heap1[0] == heap2[0]:
        # Common element, part of the intersection.
        intersection.append(heap1[0])
        heap.heappop(heap1)
        heap.heappop(heap2)
    elif heap1[0] > heap2[0]:
        heap.heappop(heap1)
    else:
        heap.heappop(heap2)

# intersection now contains the common elements of heap1 and heap2,
# in max-to-min order, so it already meets the heap invariant.
```

Answer (score 2):

If hashing is possible, do the intersection with a hash set and then heapify. This is O(n) with the usual caveats.

If hashing is not possible, do the intersection with a tree set on H1 (the smaller of the two). This is O(n log m), which is as good as it gets by the usual element distinctness lower bound.

Comment: could you explain? hashing `O(m+n)`, intersect `O(m)`, heapify `O(mlgm)`, sum up `O(n+mlgm)`. why it's linear?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr you forgot about linear time bottom-up heapify

Comment: @harold oh crap. bad memory.